# Understanding bools in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn some Python and had a question about a really small "program" I made as a test.

```
    a = input()
    print(a)
    b = '10'
    if a == b:
       print("Yes")
    else:
       print("No")
```

This works, but my question is why does the value for b have to have the quotes around it.

Comment: Because it's the string `"10"` instead of the integer `10`.  `input()` returns strings, so if you want to check for equality, you have to compare to another string.

Comment: `input()` returns a string. A good way to find out about such things is to start the python interpreter and type `help(input)` e.g.

Comment: `a` is a string because it comes from `input()`. It can only possibly be equal to another string, like `'10'`, as opposed to an integer, `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. All inputs from the user are considered as `string` values by python. In python, you can only compare a string to string, integer to integer and so on...

You could do this as well

```
    a = int(input())
    print(a)
    b = 10
    if a == b:
       print("Yes")
    else:
       print("No")
```

Over here `int()` converts the value you enter to an integer. So you don't need quotes for the variable `b`

Answer (score 2):

Python `input()` function will by default take any input that you give and store it as a string.

---

> why does the value for b have to have the quotes around it

Well, it doesn't have to have quotes. But if you need the condition to evaluate to True, then you need quotes. So, since `a` is a string, you need to have `b = '10'` with the quotation mark if you need `a == b` to evaluate to True.

If your input is an integer, you could also do `a = int(input())` and in this case, `b=10` would work as well. Simple !

So, the following two can be considered to be equivalent in terms of the result they give -

```
a = input()

b = '10'
if a == b:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

AND

```
a = int(input())

b = 10
if a == b:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `input()` is a string, therefore you must compare it to a string. Everyone learning programming starts off with many questions, and it is the only way to learn, so do not feel bad about it.

Answer (score 1):

In python default input type is string. if you want it as `int` you must cast it:

```
a = int(input()) #change type of input from string to int
print(type(a))
b = 10
if a == b:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```